# How to use an interceptor without annotations on generic classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unity-container, interceptor

Seeking a solution for both .Net Framework MVC 4.6.2 and .Net Core 3.1 using Microsoft Unity Framework.  The code that is being called is from an auto-generated interface:

```
public interface ItemApi 
{
    Item GetItem (int itemId, int token1, string token2);
}
```

This is only an example of one of many, many interfaces and their methods.  All of them have the final two audit values, token1 & token2.  Rather than always making the developer pass in these values, the goal is to create an interceptor to aid the developer by setting these values so the developer can focus on the task at hand.

After reading through all the documentation on Castle Windsor's Dynamic Proxy and Dora no answers presented themselves.  In all the research it looks like methods always need an annotation for the interceptor to work.  Is there a way to create an interceptor that will work on all methods, regardless of attributes?  If so, can someone point to an example?

Comment: Can you just create a façade class and use that instead?

Comment: I had not thought of that.  I would prefer not, the reason is the interface in question is a RESTful call generated by OpenAPI.  Each and every RESTful service we write would first have to be autogenerated, then the facade would have to be manually managed.  I think that would be a nightmare!